# Run an ubuntu instance with virtualbox in bash?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, mac-osx-server

I've used VirtualBox on a mac server, to run Ubuntu server instances, and I've liked it.

However I have a little bit of difficulty, because VirtualBox seems to be a GUI thing, so I SVN into my mac server, and use the GUI to run it, It would be great if I could somehow run an ubuntu (server) instance, from shell when I SSH into it.

I'm looking for a simple way I don't want to get too much into advanced virtualization tools/methods, something like VirtualBox or VirtualBox itself would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this VirtualBox using [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html). This should be included by default on any VirtualBox install.

`VBoxManage startvm NAME --type=headless`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [phpvirtualbox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/) as a web based front-end to VirtualBox.